# How to use sortBy after groupBy in collect in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I need after get query from sql with Eloquent, create `groupBy('date')` and `sortBy('price')` with `collect` in `Laravel 5.3`.

In `IndexController`:

```
$flights = Flights::GetFlights($fromCity, $toCity, $fromDate);

$collection = collect($flights);

$sortFlight = $collection->groupBy('date')->sortBy('price');
```

In `Model`:

```
public function scopeGetFlights($query, $fromCity, $toCity, $fromDate)
{
    // Between dates
    $beforeDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromDate . '- 10 days'));
    $afterDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromDate . '+ 10 days'));

    $join = $query
        -> join('airlines', 'airlines.pana', 'flights.airline')
        -> where('flights.from_city', $fromCity)
        -> where('flights.to_city', $toCity)
        -> whereBetween('flights.date', [$beforeDate, $afterDate])
        -> get([
                 'flights.*',
                 'airlines.pana as pana',
                 'airlines.name as airlineName'
              ]);
    return $join;
}
```

Then `Print_r($sortFlight)`, After print `groupBy('date')` is works
 but `sortBy('price')` does not work!!!!

Where is my problem?

Comment: Hi @Punit.. , How to use `sortBy('flights.price')` in collect ?

Answer (score 5):

My solution for sorting values in a grouped collection in Laravel

```
$sponsors = Sponsor::with('sponsor_level')->whereStatus(1)->get();

// grouped by sponsor level name
$grouped = $sponsors->sortBy('sponsor_level.order')->groupBy(function($item, $key){
    return $item->sponsor_level->name;
});

// finally sorted by sponsor name inside the group
return $grouped->map(function($item, $key){
    return $item->sortBy('name');
});
```

You can chain these of course, I separated for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortby)

> The sortBy method sorts the collection by the given key. The sorted collection keeps the original array keys, so in this example we'll use the values method to reset the keys to consecutively numbered indexes:

So after doing `groupBy()` do as follows.

```
$sorted = $collection->groupBy('date')->sortBy('price');
$sorted->values()->all();
```

Comment: Hi, How to use `groupBy` in collect ?

Comment: The way you've done groupBy() is correct. Just add the sortBy() part to the result of groupBy()

Comment: Plus, you don't have to do `$collection = collect($flights);`. do `GetFlights()->get()` and it is a collection.

Comment: After applying sortBy(). it is sorting the whole collection

Comment: I need create `groupBy` by `date` in `collect` then after `groupBy`, i need sort by `price` this `groupBy`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this single line

```
$sortFlight = $collection->groupBy('date')->sortBy('price')->values()->all();
```

Comment: Hi, ` $collection->groupBy('date')->sortBy('price')->values()->all();` does not work!

Comment: No, I do not want `groupBy` in Eloquent. I need use to collect.

Comment: what do you want first groupby dates and withing these group by sort by price price or after grouping by date again sort by price in whole query ?

Comment: I need create `groupBy` by `date` then after `groupBy`, i need sort by `price` this `groupBy`